# On click of visual force tab i need to insert a new Record

Tags: apex, tab

I have created the visaual force tab and whenever i click on that tab i need to insert a new record in some object how can i achieve this

Comment: Hi, your question is very broad to answer.. can you share your current code that you have tried and highlight what you are after.

Comment: Do you really need to create your own page? Maybe standard one - creating tab for object is sufficient?

Comment: fallen phantasm yes we have to use visualforce tab but i would be glad if you ca please say how can we get that work around for even normal tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do DML operation(insert record) from constructor of the visualforce page. It is not allowed due to security reasons.

If you want to work around it, you can use **action** attribute in `<apex:page>` tag. It will let you execute your controller method when page is loading. So write the code to insert record in this separate method(no inside constructor). Call it from action attribute in `<apex:page>` tag.

Comment: I hope it works i will be trying and let you know